# Aggregation with Dimensions not working

Tags: sql, aggregate, dimensions

I have a SQL table with several dimensions on it, when I aggregate it by day one dimensions, I get the right number, but when I add more dimensions I get a different number.
This is super strange
SK_DATE
SK_COUNTRY
Number1
Number2

So if I do

```
SELECT
    SK_DATE
    ,MAX(number1)
    ,MAX(number2)
FROM
    table 1
GROUP BY
    SK_DATE
;
```

No when I run the same thing. however, this time

```
SELECT
    SK_DATE
    ,SK_COUNTRY
    ,MAX(number1)
    ,MAX(number2)
FROM
    table 1
GROUP BY
    SK_DATE
    ,SK_COUNTRY
;
```

so on the first run I receive 5.2M for number 1 but when I run the second query I receive 6.4M

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add sample table data, the current result and the expected result. All as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got more values of SK_COUNTRY in a single SK_Date, you should expect that the number of rows will bloat. Since Aggregation will be based on on unique combination of SK_DATE and SK_COUNTRY

```
SELECT
SK_DATE
,SK_COUNTRY
,MAX(number1)
,MAX(number2)
FROM
table 1
GROUP BY
SK_DATE
,SK_COUNTRY
 ;
```